# How to delete all data from a user but exclude certain data

Tags: mysql

I have two different types of users and they can have the same user id. I only want to delete the data from user type A in the tables 'media' and 'notifications'. Therefore I use the WHERE function. This works well because I only delete the type A users. But when these users don't exists in the 'media' and/or 'notifications table all data in the other tables is not delete because they don't match the WHERE requirements.

So my question is: how can I delete all data of the users which match the WHERE requirements and IF they don't exist in the 'media' and 'notifications' table still DELETE all data from the other tables.

Here is the query I use right now:

```
DELETE `cards`, `users`,`media`,`notifications`
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `cards` ON `cards`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `media` ON `media`.`model_id` = `users`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `notifications` ON `notifications`.`notifiable_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `users`.`id` = 88 AND `media`.`model_type` LIKE '%User%' AND `notifications`.`type` LIKE '%Workseeker%'
```

All help is welcome! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
DELETE `cards`, `users`,`media`,`notifications`
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `cards` ON `cards`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `media` ON `media`.`model_id` = `users`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `notifications` ON `notifications`.`notifiable_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `users`.`id` = 88 AND (`media`.`model_type` LIKE '%User%' OR `media`.`model_type` IS NULL) AND (`notifications`.`type` LIKE '%Workseeker%' OR `notifications`.`type` IS NULL)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks mate!

Comment: If this answer has worked, could you please press the checkmark next to it?